# Python mapping attributes to multiple other formats

Tags: python, json

We're currently building an in house service to manage our users. Our challenge is syncing to multiple 3rd party systems that have disparate formats (though all in JSON).

As an example our User Schema could look like the below

```
{
"title": "User Schema",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "firstName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "lastName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "email": {
        "type": "string"
    }
"required": ["firstName", "lastName"]
}
```

At a later point we need to transform this set of data for several other vendors that might have all or some of the fields

e.g. vendor 1

```
{
    "first_name": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "last_name": {
        "type": "string"
    },
}
```

e.g. vendor 2

```
{
    "fname": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "lname": {
        "type": "string"
    },
}
```

We'd need to map firstName and lastName to each of the alternative formats above for each vendor. I feel like we should be able to just shove this data into the JSON schema and do the transformations with python easily enough.

It's basically just data transformation. Is there a standard format or package in Python that can assist in the transformation?

I'm thinking something below would be a starting point but unsure.

```
{
"title": "User Schema",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "firstName": {
        "type": "string",
        "vendorMap" {
           "vendor1": "first_name",
           "vendor2": "last_name"
        }
    },
    "lastName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "email": {
        "type": "string"
    }
"required": ["firstName", "lastName"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary for each vendor and their mappings:

```
transformers = {'v2': {
                    'fname': 'first_name', 
                    'lname': 'last_name'}}

vendor = 'v2'
# Sample data from vendor 'v2'.
v2 = {
    "fname": "John",
    "lname": "Smith",
    "email": "john@example.com",
    "random": "randomly keyed data"
}

# Convert data into standard form.
transformed_data = {
    transformers[vendor].get(k, k) if vendor in transformers else k: v 
    for k, v in v2.iteritems()}

>>> transformed_data
{'email': 'john@example.com',
 'first_name': 'John',
 'last_name': 'Smith',
 'random': 'randomly keyed data'}
```

If ordering is important, consider using an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects)

Comment: This looks close to what I was thinking. I was just hoping we could better consolidate the multiple schemas  but the transformers does make sense.

Comment: You could use the same approach for the schemas to first validate the JSON.  It still needs to put into a standard format, however.